# In finite field why $\overline c = -c \ne 0$ for $\overline c = c^{p^f}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $GF(p^{2f})$ be a finite field of order $p^{2f}$. Consider the map $\overline x := x^{p^f}$ for $x \in GF(p^{2f})$. Let $b \in GF(p^{2f}) - GF(p^f)$ and set $c := b - \overline b$.

> Why do we have $\overline c = -c$ and $c \ne 0$?

I see that $\overline{\overline{c}} = c$. But is this enough to conlude both statements?

Comment: Yes, this gives $\overline{\overline{c}} = c$, but why $\overline c+ c = 0$?

Comment: Oh really, I do not wanted to assume that $\overline{a+b} = \overline{a} + \overline{b}$ holds, as in the prototypical example of a field like $\mathbb Q$ we have $(a+b)^k \ne a^k + b^k$. And also why $c \ne 0$?

Comment: Okay. Thank you, if you want you can assemble your comments in an answer, so I can mark this question as answered and you get the reputation for it. (btw is it correct english to say "assemble your comments", or should it be "compile your comments", or is this all strange english, sorry I am no native speaker!)

Comment: Ok, I will do. But may I ask one last question, why $b^{p^f} = b$ implies $b \in GF(p^f)$, is it because the multiplicative group is cyclic and has one unique group of order $p^f - 1$ then. And do we have $b^{p^{kf}} = b$ implies $b \in GF(p^{kf})$ for $k = 1,\ldots, n$ and the subfields $GF(p^{kf}) \subseteq GF(p^{nf})$, or is this just valid for $k = 1$?

Comment: Stefan, let me give the following analogy. The point here is that $x\mapsto \overline{x}$ is an automorphism of order two. You said it yourself: $\overline{\overline{c}}=c$. That is just like the usual complex conjugation. And just like in usual complex conjugation:
$$\overline{\overline{c}-c}=c-\overline{c}.$$ More or less because $\overline{c}-c$ is pure imaginary so negative to its complex conjugate. The same argument works for all automorphism of order two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the subfield $GF(p^f)$ consists exactly of the roots of $X^n - X$ for $n = p^f$, we have $c \ne 0$ for $b \notin GF(p^f)$. Further as $(x+y)^p = x^p + y^p$ in finite fields we have $\overline{x + y} = \overline x + \overline y$. This gives $\overline c = \overline{b - \overline b} = \overline b - b = -(b - \overline b) = -c$.